# How to remove links from paddings between menu items

Tags: html, css, list, navbar

I'm trying to make a norizonal list menu
I applied some paddings between each menu item

I'd like to know, how to add padding between them
Without making those paddings linkable

[image]

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use `margin` not `padding` ?

Comment: It makes sense, but your current html/css would help, more than image...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I guess you have something similar to:

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
```

Use this CSS for the above scenario:

```
li {margin-right: 100px;}
```